# I can't add cuts to a plane

Tags: edit-mode

There are three planes in this scene.
I believe each one of them is composed of only 4 vertexes.

I had no problem selecting the one on the bottom and adding cuts to it. 
But when I select the one on top left, I can't add cuts. The bottom text line tells me there are cuts being added, but I cannot see them and obviously this is a bug... ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share this file. Could be for a number of reasons.

Comment: Are you sure the selected face not to be a ngon face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pick a direction**

The operation you are trying to perform is called "**Loop cuts and slide**": basically recognize on the mesh faces a certain flow of polygons (loop) and allow the user to subdivide the interested faces by adding a given amount of edges.

What the command need to run is just the direction of the path. Quad faces can in fact be subdivided in **two different directions**.

Till the cursor does't approach one of the edges, you'll not see the pink edges (the future loop cuts).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, there may be a terminology issue here. It looks to me that the object in your screenshot contains three faces, perhaps from a cube mesh object, but not necessarily three planes.

Next, I agree with iKlsR that it would be helpful if you would upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit a link into your question to make it easier for others who might with to assist you.

If you are attempting to use the subdivide tool (<kbd>W</kbd>key > subdivide) to make your divisions, that tool works on faces whose edges have the same number of sides. If, before doing the subdivide operation, you select all of the faces you want to subdivide, the tool will do as you suppose. However, if you select one face, and subdivide it, the other two faces do not have the same number of faces on each edge as the selected one, so the algorithm cannot determine where to make the subdivisions on the three unsubdivided edges. If you want to use the subdivide tool to subdivide multiple faces, select all of the faces before you begin the subdivision.